# Need help with a particle system

Tags: particles

I'm working on a basic animation, and am having trouble getting the effect I want from a particle system. I have a cube inside the torch object giving off "smoke" particles, that's parented to the torches' motion, and I want there to be a particle every few seconds that slowly rises straight up. I tried turning down the emission number, and turned off the gravity, but the particle always starts behind the back of the torch, and then moves ahead of it while going up. How can I get it to start from the cube inside the top of the torch, and not move while the cube moves?
[image]
[image]

[image] (With @eromod's answer)

Comment: can you include your .blend file? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 3):

- Make a wind forcefield.
- Make a particle system that isnt effected by gravity, has no starting velocity, and has some brownian motion.[image]

I think you are asking how to have the particles only come from the top of the torch with no particles coming from the bottom? Just weight paint it and remove/re-enable it in the particle system so that it updates

[image]

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here. Please go into a little more detail about how to set it up properly

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33615)

Comment: I have to put effort in my answer? thanks for the reminder.

Comment: The particles are moving really weirdly. I'll attach my .blend file in my original post